# Capture POST request body in Sentry React

Tags: reactjs, sentry, sentryreact

Is there a way to capture the POST request body in Sentry.io when any request fails?

I am using `@sentry/react` and `"@sentry/tracing` version `^7.16.0`

```
const onSubmit = async ({foo, bar}: IForm) => {
    try {
      await fetch(
        `http://localhost:3001/v1/test`,
        {
          method: "POST",
          body: JSON.stringify({
            foo,
            bar,
          }),
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      Sentry.captureException(err);
    }
}
```

It looks like the entire body is skipped from tracking in Sentry at all:

```
Sentry.init({
  dsn: process.env.REACT_APP_SENTRY_DSN,
  environment: process.env.REACT_APP_SENTRY_ENV,
  integrations: [new BrowserTracing()],
  tracesSampleRate: 1.0,
  // Filtering important sensitive data before sending to Sentry.io
  beforeBreadcrumb(breadcrumb, hint) {
    console.log('beforeBreadcrumb breadcrumb: ', breadcrumb) // no post request body here
    console.log('beforeBreadcrumb hint: ', hint) // no post request body here as well

    return breadcrumb;
  },
  beforeSend(event, hint) {
    console.log("beforeSend hint: ", hint); // no post request body here
    console.log("beforeSend event: ", event); // no post request body here as well
        
    return event;
  },
})
```

And of course, there is no request body(foo/bar object) in the Sentry dashboard.

Is there any way to always add the POST request body/payload to each failed request exception?

Of course, I can add breadcrumbs before sending the request, but it would be nice to have this working by default.